# Batch: convert pipe delimited text file to comma delimited csv file

Tags: batch-file

I have a `.txt` file like this:

> ```
> Customer Number||Customer Name||Partner Number||Partner Name||Customer Country
> 1ABC||Jame||1234||Anny||USA
> 2DEF||Susan||5678||Prissy||UK
> ```

My output should be a `.csv` file with no empty columns.

This is what I tried:

```
@echo off
setlocal disableDelayedExpansion
set input="C:\a.txt"
set output="C:\Customer_Pipe.csv"
>%output% (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in ('input"') do (
        set line=%%a
        setlocal enableDelayedExpansion
        echo "!line:|=","!">>"%~2"
    )
)
```

Comment: Ok. Do you have a question?

Comment: @RB. I need to write a batch file.to do that

Comment: Ok. And what is preventing you doing that? (Note that StackOverflow is not a code-writing service. We can help you with specific issues you face, but will not just write code for you)

Comment: I am new to batch files.It would be better if someone write the code and explain @RB.

Comment: Please can you edit your question to include your code. Showing that you have made a genuine attempt is one of the most important ways to get people to answer your question :)

Comment: Now I have added it @RB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

If you want to read the file stored in variable `INPUT`, you need to read it as `%INPUT%` to do that (you stated `INPUT` literally, with odd quotation). When you specify `''` within the set of `for /F`, the part within `()` is interpreted as a command rather than a file, so `for /F` tries to execute command `input` which cannot be found and so the script fails. I stringly recommend to put `""` around the specified file, together with the `usebackq` option, in order to avoid trouble with white-spaces in paths/file names.

If you want to write into the file stored in variable `OUTPUT`, you must not redirect the `echo` to somewhere else (you placed `>>"%~2"` in the code).

Here is the code as I would write it:

```dos
@echo off
setlocal EnableExtensions DisableDelayedExpansion

rem Define constants here:
set "INPUT=%~1"
set "OUTPUT=%~2"

if not defined INPUT exit /B 1
if not defined OUTPUT set "OUTPUT=con"
> "%OUTPUT%" (
    for /F usebackq^ delims^=^ eol^= %%L in ("%INPUT%") do (
        set "LINE=%%L"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        echo(!LINE:^|^|=,!
        endlocal
    )
)

endlocal
exit /B
```

The input file for the batch program must be provided as the first command line argument. The second argument (optional) is the output file.

Note that this script does not check whether the input data contains `,` characters, which impact the way the converted file is treated. If you want to put quotation marks around all fields of the returned CSV data to avoid data interpretation troubles, replace the above `echo` command line by:

```
echo("!LINE:||=","!"
```

The output data (with the original `echo` command line) looks like this:

> ```
> Customer Number,Customer Name,Partner Number,Partner Name,Customer Country
> 1ABC,Jame,1234,Anny,USA
> 2DEF,Susan,5678,Prissy,UK
> ```

The output data with the modified `echo` command line looks like this:

> ```
> "Customer Number","Customer Name","Partner Number","Partner Name","Customer Country"
> "1ABC","Jame","1234","Anny","USA"
> "2DEF","Susan","5678","Prissy","UK"
> ```

Comment: I am new to stackoverflow and i dont have enough reputations to do it.. sorry.. and Is there any ways to delete all white spaces in the text file and then converting it to csv in the same batch you helped me with.. @aschipfl

Comment: Accepting (ticking the green checkmark) is always possible, independent on the reputation status. To remove spaces, you could insert `set "LINE=!LINE: =!"` immediately before the `echo` command line; to remove tabs, simply add another line (with the space replaced by a tab, of course); you can do that with any characters; actually this replaces the given string between the `:` and the `=` (a _space_ here) by the string after the `=` (nothing here) (see also `set /?`)...

Answer (score 0):

There are two problems in your code.

1)
You use `setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion`, that's a good idea, but you have to close it with `endlocal` else you get an error after ~32 setlocals.

2)
Your replace functions looks a bit odd.
You add some quotes, they will be part of the output later.
You could try this.
`echo(!line:^|^|=,!`

At all

```
>%output% (
    for /f "tokens=*" %%a in (%input%) do (
        set "line=%%a"
        setlocal EnableDelayedExpansion
        set "line=!line:||=,!"
        (echo(!line!)
        endlocal
    )
)
```

Comment: It works but the csv file contains the path specified as input(C:\a.txt),not the data in the text file. @jeb

Comment: @Gowtham.S, this can only happen if `%INPUT%` contains a file path enclosed in `""`...